# Angular Check value in array directly in template

Tags: angular

in my ng app I'm working with roles. All roles are stored in an array. How can I check if a role exists in my html template without doing something like this:

```
  <div class="customer-entry" *ngFor="role of userRoles">
    <div *ngIf="role == 'Admin' || role == 'Superuser'">
      <span class="badge badge-warning">allowed</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my opinion there must be a solution to do this without a ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a structural directive for this:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
     selector: '[hasRole]' 
})
export class HasRoleDirective {

    constructor( private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                 private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                 private userService: UserService) { }
    @Input() set hasRole(role: string) {
       if (this.userService.getRole() === role) {
          this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
       } else {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
      } 
    }
}
```

You now can use the directive like this:

```
<div *hasRole="'Admin'">
  <span class="badge badge-warning">allowed</span>
</div>
```

Benefit would be that you can use it anywhere in your project without duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using a pipe, this is also faster (if it's pure) than using a service

```
@Pipe({ name: 'hasPermission' })
export class HasPermission implements PipeTransform {

  transform(permissions: string[], required: string[]): boolean {
    return permissions.some((current) => required.some((req) => current === req));
  }
}
```

Use it as

```
 <div class="customer-entry" *ngIf="userRoles | hasPermission: ['Admin', 'Superuser']">
    <div>
      <span class="badge badge-warning">allowed</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or

```
  <div class="customer-entry" *ngFor="lot role of userRoles">
    <div *ngIf="[role] | hasPermission: ['Admin', 'Superuser']">
      <span class="badge badge-warning">allowed</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Haven't tested it, this is just a prototype